# Null id property when deserialize json with jackson and Jackson2HalModule of Spring Hateoas

Tags: java, jackson, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas, hal

My entity :

```
public class User {

    private Integer id;
    private String mail;
    private boolean enabled;

    // getters and setters
}
```

File test.json (response from REST webservice) :

```
{
 "_embedded" : {
  "users" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "mail" : "admin@admin.com",
    "enabled" : true,
    "_links" : {
      "self" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1"
      }
    }
  } ]
 }
}
```

And my test class :

```
public class TestJson {

    private InputStream is;
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        is = TestJson.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.json");
    }

    @After
    public void after() throws IOException {
        is.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        PagedResources<Resource<User>> paged = mapper.readValue(is, new TypeReference<PagedResources<Resource<User>>>() {});
        Assert.assertNotNull(paged.getContent().iterator().next().getContent().getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void testResource() throws IOException {
        PagedResources<User> paged = mapper.readValue(is, new TypeReference<PagedResources<User>>() {});
        Assert.assertNotNull(paged.getContent().iterator().next().getId());
    }
}
```

The second test passes but not the first. I don't understand because the id property in the user is the only one missing (mail and enabled properties are not empty)...

What do I have to do to fix it ? Is it a bug in Jackson or Spring Jackson2HalModule ?

You can reproduce by cloning my spring-hateoas fork [repository](https://github.com/mfalaize/spring-hateoas) and launching unit tests.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, it was due to the `Resource` class which is built to wrap the content of your bean. The content property is annotated by `@JsonUnwrapped` so that the `Resource` class can map your bean in this property whereas in the json, bean properties are at the same level as `_links` property. With this annotation, it is possible to have property name conflict with the wrapper and the inner bean. It is exactly the case here because `Resource` class has an `id` property inherited from the `ResourceSupport` class, and this property is sadly annotated by `@JsonIgnore`.

There is a workaround for this issue. You can create a new `MixIn` class inherited from the `ResourceSupportMixin` class and override the `getId()` method with `@JsonIgnore(false)` annotation :

```
public abstract class IdResourceSupportMixin extends ResourceSupportMixin {

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore(false)
    public abstract Link getId();
}
```

Then you just have to add your `IdResourceSupportMixin` class to your `ObjectMapper` :

```
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(ResourceSupport.class, IdResourceSupportMixin.class);
```

It should solve the problem.

Comment: same problem with `spring-hateoas` and `spring-boot`, so I had to rename the `id` to something else

Comment: It was a year ago but if I remember correctly, it actually doesn't work because of a compilation error I think... The only one solution I found is cahen's one. You have to rename your id property to something else.

Comment: This works for me: `objectMapper.addMixIn(Resource.class, IdResourceSupportMixIn.class);` - with jackson 2.8.8 and spring-hateoas 0.28, and rest template. But it breaks `response.getBody().getId()`

Comment: ResourceSupportMixin is package private. We can not extend it. But I have found solution.  Use this.

```
public abstract class IdResourceSupportMixin extends ResourceSupport {

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore(false)
    public abstract Link getId();

    @Override
    @XmlElement(name = "link")
    @JsonProperty("_links")
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @JsonSerialize(using = Jackson2HalModule.HalLinkListSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = Jackson2HalModule.HalLinkListDeserializer.class)
    public abstract List<Link> getLinks();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code you find all @Entity beans an change the config to expose Id value:

```
 import java.util.LinkedList;
 import java.util.List;

 import javax.persistence.Entity;

 import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider;
 import org.springframework.core.type.filter.AnnotationTypeFilter;
 import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
 import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

 import com.rvillalba.exampleApiHateoas.entity.Example;

 import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

 @Component
 @Slf4j
 public class SpringDataRestCustomization extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override
     public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
         listMatchingClasses(Entity.class).forEach(entity -> config.exposeIdsFor(entity));
     }

     public List<Class> listMatchingClasses(Class annotationClass) {
         List<Class> classes = new LinkedList<Class>();
         ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(true);
         scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(annotationClass));
         for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents(Example.class.getPackage().getName())) {
             try {
                 classes.add(Class.forName(bd.getBeanClassName()));
             } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                 log.error("listMatchingClasses problem", e);
             }
         }
         return classes;
     }

 }
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Thanks @Raul Villalba. I replaced the `Example` class with my `BaseEntity` where I defined `private Long id` and it worked. I also changed the class to `public class SpringDataRestCustomization implements RepositoryRestConfigurer` because `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.3.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
public class User extends ResourceSupport {

    @JsonIgnore(false)
    private Integer id;
    private String mail;
    private boolean enabled;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Also, change your `http` client to return `PagedResources <User>` instead of `PagedResources<Resource<User>>`

Comment: How did you have getter for `Integer id` field if ResourceSupport has `public Link getId()` method?

Comment: @MikhailKopylov You are right. @Will Franco - this solution doesn't work. This is the error that I see. ```'getId()' in 'com.example.entity.User' clashes with 'getId()' in 'org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport'; attempting to use incompatible return type```